# protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: linux, samba, samba4, smb-conf, smbclient

This may look like an old thread. But I tried all types of solution which are provided. But no luck.

I have a Shared Folder from fileserver(windows server 2012 R2 - default samba 2.1)

My client side configurtion are:-
Version 3.5.10-114.el6

The packages are installed :-

```
rpm -qa | grep -i samba  
samba-winbind-clients-3.5.10-114.el6.x86_64  
samba-client-3.5.10-114.el6.x86_64  
samba-3.5.10-114.el6.x86_64  
samba-common-3.5.10-114.el6.x86_64
```

The commands which I followed in Linux client

```
smbclient -L //hostname/USER -U domain/username -W domain
```

`dmesg` retruns a below error

```
[1907763.056610] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -112
```

`smbclient` error:

```
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.  
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET  
Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

Comment: Please try mounting it with sec=ntlmssp or sec=ntlmsspi as an -o (option) - smbclient complaining about SMB1 can be rectified by editing smb.conf and adding; client max protocol = SMB3 and client min protocol = SMB2_1 under [global]

If these succeed, I'll ask it as an answer with some explanation.

Comment: @Miu Thank you u for your quick reply. when I am adding the client min and max protocol, I am getting the ` Ignoring unknown parameter "Client Man Protocol `

Comment: It's "client max protocol" - also try to just mount the directory with: mount.cifs -o sec=ntlmssp,username=yourusername,domain=yourdomain //server/share /whereyouwanttoaccessit

Comment: @Miuku the same error is coming again.  mount error(112): Host is down.  client max protocol and client min protocol is showing the Ignoring unknown parameter.

Comment: Host is down? Perhaps you should try mounting it with the IP address of the server.

Comment: Tried with IP  address as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I was able to connect with:

```sh
sudo mount.cifs -o sec=ntlmssp,username=MY_USERNAME //SERVER_IP/SHARED_FOLDER ~/LOCAL_FOLDER
```

Adding `client max protocol = SMB3` and `client min protocol = SMB2_1` under `[global]` of `/etc/samba/smb.conf` caused error, I had to change SMB2_1 to SMB2. After which server said "Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available"

Answer (score 0):

The Main problem with CentOS version. After the upgrade from 6.0 to 6.10, the same `mount -t cifs` command works fine and can able to mount windows directory to CentOS server.